# I have trouble in understanding the output of the following code

Tags: pointers, operators

I have the following program :

```
int main()
{

  char arr[]  = "geeksforgeeks";

  char *ptr  = arr;

  while(*ptr != '\0')

      ++*ptr++;

  printf("%s %s", arr, ptr);

  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

Output:  `hffltgpshfflt`

Explanation given is :

If one knows the precedence and associativity of the operators then there is nothing much left. Below is the precedence of operators.

```
Postfixx ++            left-to-right
Prefix  ++             right-to-left
Dereference *          right-to-left
```

Therefore the expression `++*ptr++` has following effect :

- Value of `*ptr` is incremented
- Value of `ptr` is incremented

My question is how this pointer expression `++*ptr++` is getting implemented and why does this statement "`printf("%s %s", arr, ptr);`" not printing the string "geeksforgeeks" as well ?
Please help.

Comment: How could it possibly print "geeksforgeeks"?  All of the characters in ``arr`` have been incremented, the original string no longer exists.  Note that ``ptr`` prints out as an empty string, because it ends up pointing to the null character at the end of ``arr``.

Comment: So you mean to say that , through pointer ptr , we changed the original arr and hence the changed thing is "hffltgpshfflt" now?? @jasonharper

Comment: Yes, exactly.  ``ptr`` points to each element of ``arr`` in turn (stopping when it reaches the null character at the end), those elements are what the leading ``++`` is incrementing.

Comment: got it. Thank you :) @jasonharper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to --> why does this statement "printf("%s %s", arr, ptr);" not printing the string "geeksforgeeks" as well ?

Here,array elements of arr are incremented by 1 i.e.,g+1=h,e+1=f.... so on this is getting incremented by 1 due to ++*ptr which increments the ptr value .
ptr++ will incremented by one it means the ptr address is incremented by '1'. until the null character.

So, you are printing arr it shows the value as hffltgpshfflt and printing the ptr which is now pointing  to NULL which prints nothing. you can check the ptr value by %x format it prints 0.